# Could you help me to create a diagram in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

Excuse me, could someone help me to make the code for this diagram? I have a hard time drawing in Tikz

[image]

Comment: What do you have difficulty with? You need to draw three circles, some text nodes placed at correct positions, and an arrow.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```latex
% In the preamble
% \usepackage{tikz}
% \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,2.5) [] {$F(\mathcal{H})$};
\draw[] (0,0) circle[radius=2];
\draw[] (0,-0.5) circle[radius=1];
\node at (0,1) [] {$\tilde{\mathcal{H}}$};
\node (psi1) at (0,-0.5) [] {$\left\langle\psi\right|$};

\node at (5,2.5) [] {$\mathcal{H}$};
\draw[] (5,0) circle[radius=2];
\node (psi2) at (5,0) [] {$\left|\psi\right\rangle$};

\draw[Latex-Latex] (psi1) to[bend left] (psi2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which results in:

[image: Result from the code]

Comment: Wow, great, thank you very much, you have helped me a lot!